# link gfortran with Intel MKL

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran, intel-mkl, compiler-flags

I have an application that is written in Fortran and call Intel PARDISO for parallelization. Linking directly with PARDISO doesn't seem like a possibility because the current gfortran I'm using is 5.4.0.

What compiler options/flags do you use to link gfortran with Intel MKL, assuming that Intel MKL is installed on the computer? The MKL libraries version is 2018.0.

Thanks a lot!

Note: The application was compiled without any error using `ifort -mkl` flag that naturally links the application with Intel MKL.

Comment: Look up the Intel link advisor applet.  Should be no problem for Linux or Mac.

Comment: In the other question you say you link with MKL. Is this solved now? If yes, please write an answer or delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @tim18 that you should use the link advisor.

However to compile the test singular value decomposition program from Intel with `gfortran` the following works:

```
gfortran -I${MKLROOT}/include -fopenmp -o dgesvd dgesvd.f \
         -L${MKLROOT}/lib/ -lmkl_core -lmkl_gnu_thread -lmkl_gf_lp64
```